# Рендеринг текста при css трансформации

Tags: html, css

Есть некоторый текст, который развернут на 90deg.

```css
span {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    backface-visibility: hidden;  
  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;         
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


/* Customizer */
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <span>some text</span>
  
</div>
```

**Проблема:** Текст смазан, не корректно отображается.

**Вопрос:** Как можно исправить отображение текста (и можно ли вообще исправить), чтобы он был четким, а не "размазаным" (расплывчатым)?

**P.S:** *В данном примере он постоянно такой, в моем проекте он в таком виде, только при скролле (когда перестаешь скроллить страницу - нормально отображается).*

Comment: Лена , если к примеру добавить `font-family` то на мой взгляд проблема пропадает http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YGvBky?editors=110

Comment: хм, интересно, и не подумала шрифт заменить. Спасибо!!!

Comment: рад что помог вам!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема связана со связкой размер шрифта + "семья" шрифта. 
Исправить смазанность именно такого размера текста - возможности не будет, свойства (их размеры) не позволяют, они начинают растягиваться, расплываться. Для решения нужно брать либо больший размер, либо начинать играть с другими шрифтами, если это не так принципиально.

P.S. Для тестов на основе вашего кода размер шрифта (`font-size`) был протестирован на `27px` и `28px`, на размере большем - смазанность пропадает. Так что данный момент - мертвая точка перехода шрифта к большим буквам с четким отображением.

Тест 1 (смазанность присутствует):

```css
span {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
backface-visibility: hidden;  
  
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;         
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


/* Customizer */
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <span>some text</span>
  
</div>
```

Тест 2 (смазанность отсутствует):

```css
span {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
backface-visibility: hidden;  
  
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;         
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


/* Customizer */
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <span>some text</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!